# Computing the cohomology of $\Omega S^{2n-1} \setminus {x_0}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the cohomology of $\Omega S^{2n-1} \setminus {x_0}$ where $x_0$ is the base point. I am trying to compute it using Mayer-Vietoris sequence but I don't understand the homology of $\partial U$ where $U$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ in $\Omega S^{2n-1}$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively, the reason the homology of a manifold $M$ of $\dim M = n$ changes when you delete a point is that when you rune the Mayer-Vietoris sequence on the pair of open sets $M - \{x\}$ and $x \in U \cong \Bbb R^n$, then $U - \{x\} \cong \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\} \simeq S^{n-1}$, which has nontrivial homology and hence interacts in the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Here it is

In fact it is a general theorem that if $M$ is an infinite-dimensional manifold (modeled on either $\Bbb R^\infty$ or some Hilbert or Banach space $V$; probably for the Frechet setting as well, but I am ignorant) then for any finite-dimensional tamely embedded submanifold $F \subset M$, the inclusion $i: M \setminus F \to M$ is in fact a homotopy equivalence. Deleting something of *infinite* codimension doesn't change the homotopy type. The standard proof is by a transversality argument. (Every map $S^k \to M$ is homotopic to one transverse to $F$; every map $D^k \to M$ whose boundary is transverse to $F$ is homotopic rel boundary to one transverse to $F$. Use that $F$ has infinite codimension to see that $i$ induces an isomorphism on all homotopy groups.)

---

This more general statement is not necessary for your very simple case: the point is that since $\Omega M$ ought to make you think of an infinite-dimensional manifold, deleting something small like a point ought to change nothing.

> Theorem: If $M$ is a connected metrizable topological manifold with a basepoint $b$, then $\Omega M \setminus c_b$ (that is, the loopspace $\Omega M$ less the constant path at $b$) has the same homology as $\Omega M$.

Proof: Pick an open set $b \in U \subset M$ with $U \cong \Bbb R^n$ via a homeomorphism sending $b$ to $0$. Then $\Omega U \subset \Omega M$ is an open set containing $c_b$ (by definition of the compact-open topology, which is the topology on a loopspapce) with $$\Omega U \cong C^0(S^1, \Bbb R^n)_b = V,$$ where the subscript $b$ means we take the linear subspace of $C^0(S^1, \Bbb R^n)$ of those loops with $\gamma(1) = 0$ (the based loops).

This is a Banach space, equipped with the supremum norm (whose topology coincides with the compact-open topology). We have $\Omega U \setminus c_b \cong V \setminus \{0\} \simeq S(V)$, with $S(V)$ being the unit sphere. Unit spheres in infinite dimensional normed spaces are contractible, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2044990?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) for a reference proving a more complicataed fact. Thus $\Omega U \setminus c_b$ is contractible.

Then $(\Omega M \setminus c_b) \cup \Omega U = \Omega M$, and both $\Omega U$ and $\Omega U \setminus c_b$ are contractible, hence the Mayer-Vietoris sequence collapses to show that $H_*(\Omega M \setminus c_b) \cong H_* \Omega M$. Nothing changes whatsoever.

The technical irritation of this answer can be simplified if you learn a little bit about transversality theory as in the proof outlined near the beginning.

Comment: Great answer! (This is too small of a correction to be submitted as an edit, but you probably meant to write "Pick an open set $b \in U \subset M$..." and likewise, "homeomorphism sending $b$ to $0$).